# how to enable use check boxes to select item in windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I have required in our window application choose multiple file in tablet. In the desktop and laptop press CTRL and choose file but in the tablet not this possible. So i want to enable  "folder option" check boxes. So in the tablet choose multiple file press/ select check box in window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use this snipped code in our application. I was change in the registry of the user window change and enable "folder option" check boxes.

I was actually change in the registry in window.

```
private static void checkBoxeEnable()
        {
            var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c" + "\""+System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Turn_On_Check_Boxes_to_Select_Items.bat\"");
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

        }
```

This is the file use the register enable code"Turn_On_Check_Boxes_to_Select_Items.bat"

Code of snipped of this file...

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V AutoCheckSelect /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`CheckedListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a normal file dialog. You should work on it to enable navigating to parent and children folders.